# Superalgebra and BRST supersymmetry 1: odd vs even

Tags: string-theory, mathematical-physics, group-theory, supersymmetry, lie-algebra

It is said that [most of theories, the even elements of the superalgebra correspond to bosons and odd elements to fermions (but this is not always true; for example, the BRST supersymmetry is the other way around).](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_superalgebra).

- Why BRST supersymmetry is the other way around: odd  elements of the superalgebra correspond to bosons and even elements to fermions ?

Answer (score 3):

1. It is not completely clear what the quote from the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_superalgebra) (October, 2020) mentioned by OP refers to.

   - Perhaps it refers to that e.g. the Yang-Mills Grassmann-even gauge parameter $\xi^a$ in the gauge transformation $\delta A_{\mu}=D_{\mu}\xi^a$ is related to the Grassmann-odd FP ghost $c^a$ in the BRST formulation.
   - Perhaps it refers to the shifted Grassmann-grading in the [antibracket/Gerstenhaber algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gerstenhaber_algebra) used in the [Batalin-Vilkovisky (BV) formulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batalin%E2%80%93Vilkovisky_formalism).
2. [Bosons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boson) and [fermions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermion) are by definition$^1$ physical particles that follow Bose-Einstein and Fermi-Dirac statistics, respectively, but e.g. [Faddeev-Popov (FP) ghosts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faddeev%E2%80%93Popov_ghost) (and many auxiliary fields in the BRST formulation) are *not* physical fields, and therefore *not* bosons or fermions. Instead they first and foremost carry Grassmann-parity, although they (in the Hamiltonian formulation) often satisfy a [CCR/CAR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CCR_and_CAR_algebras).

--

$^1$ In supermathematics, which deals with [supernumbers](https://planetmath.org/supernumber), it is common to refer to Grassmann-even and Grassmann-odd variables as bosons and fermions, respectively, but it is strictly speaking a misnomer.