# Superalgebra and BRST supersymmetry 2: why Lie algebra and groups?

Tags: string-theory, mathematical-physics, group-theory, supersymmetry, lie-algebra

This follows a comment to split to a 2nd question [Superalgebra and BRST supersymmetry 1: odd vs even](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/589393/42982)

It is said that [most of theories, the even elements of the superalgebra correspond to bosons and odd elements to fermions (but this is not always true; for example, the BRST supersymmetry is the other way around).](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_superalgebra).

- Is BRST supersymmetry necessary and sufficient to be in the forms of [Lie superalgebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_superalgebra)? (Does BRST supersymmetry generate some Lie group manifolds if it has Lie superalgebra? Or can BRST supersymmetry generate exotics beyond?

Answer (score 2):

More generally a gauge algebra (which is encoded into the BRST formulation of a gauge theory) form a super [Lie](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Lie+algebroid) [algebroid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_algebroid), which in turn sometimes can be integrated to a super [Lie](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Lie+groupoid) [groupoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_groupoid).